# How can I install spark instant messenger client 2.6.3?

Tags: instant-messaging

I downloaded `spark_2_6_3.tar.gz` from http://www.igniterealtime.org/downloads/index.jsp.

After extracting the file and cding into Spark, I ran both `./starter` and `./Spark` but the messenger client is not running. I am using Ubuntu 11.10, 64 bit.

Comment: have you got java installed?  If so - is this openjre or oracle jre?  which version?

Answer (score 1):

One of a few things might be wrong:

1. Your script your trying to run isn't executable
2. You version of Java  is not quite right for the Spark client:

   sudo apt-get install galternatives

   sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ferramroberto/java

   sudo apt-get update

   sudo apt-get install sun-java6-jdk sun-java6-plugin

   (then use Gnome galternatives GUI to set the default)
3. Something else...

Comment: sun-java6 does not exist in the repositories since 11.10.  This is because Oracle's licensing on Java is incompatible with Ubuntu's packaging license requirements.  Refer to https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Java for information about how to install Oracle java

Comment: It requires Sun java to work, java 1.6 is apparently supported and works for me